# Set a variable in SQL and use that variable to figure out how many boxes are needed to fit a list of items given their dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a SQL query where, given a list of items, I figure out how many boxes (cartons) I need to fit all the items.

In my scenario, there are two types of items. CA items and PG items. CA stands for Cartons and are items that are already assembled pre-packed boxes filled with items that you are not supposed to open. So one CA item = one box to the total box count. PG items are the individual items and is pretty much the meat of the whole query. So CA items come as already pre-packed boxes, but PG items are the actual items themselves and the goal is to calculate how much cartons are needed to pack all the PG items.

I coded up what I am looking for in psuedocode, but I am not sure how I would turn it into real code.

```
DECLARE @TotalWeightVar int
DECLARE @TotalFeetVar int
DECLARE @CartonMaxVolume int
DECLARE @CartonMaxWeight int

SET @TotalWeightVar = 0
SET @TotalFeetVar = 0
SET @CartonMaxVolume = 0
SET @CartonMaxWeight = 0

SELECT T.Cust_Po,

    ISNULL(SUM (T.TWEIGHT), '0') TotalWeight,

    ISNULL(cast((SUM (T.TFEET)) as numeric(9,2)), '0' ) TotalFeet,

    SET @TotalWeightVar = SUM (CASE WHEN T.PROD_UDF4 = 'PG' THEN T.TWEIGHT END )
    SET @TotalFeetVar = SUM (CASE WHEN T.PROD_UDF4 = 'PG' THEN T.TFEET END )
    SET @CartonMaxVolume = 480
    SET @CartonMaxWeight = 40

    -- I need it to calculate both the CA half the PG half and then add them together, is this the way to do it? 
    SUM (
        -- If it's a CA item we just count the quantity of the item as the amount of Cartons needed.
        CASE WHEN T.PROD_UDF4 = 'CA' 
            THEN T.QTY_ORIGNL
        --Then we count the total amount of cartons needed to fit all the PG items. 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN T.PROD_UDF4 = 'PG' 
            -- if the total weight is not greater than the carton max weight and the total cube fits inside one carton
                CASE WHEN @TotalWeightVar < @CartonMaxWeight AND @TotalFeetVar < @CartonMaxVolume
    --              -- use one carton
                    THEN 1
                ELSE
                -- take the max of (total weight / carton max weight) OR (total volume / max carton volume)
                MAX( @TotalWeightVar / @CartonMaxWeight AND @TotalFeetVar / @CartonMaxVolume)
            END
        END
    ) TotalCartons


FROM (

Select

    Purchase_Order_Number,
    d.PRODUCT,

    d.QTY_ORIGNL,

    c.WEIGHT,
    c.LENGTH,
    c.WIDTH,
    c.HEIGHT,

    CASE WHEN 
        c.WEIGHT is NULL 
            THEN NULL 
        ELSE
            (c.WEIGHT*d.QTY_ORIGNL)
        END TWEIGHT,

    CASE 
    WHEN c.LENGTH is NULL or c.WIDTH is NULL or c.HEIGHT is NULL 
            THEN NULL 
        ELSE 
            (((c.LENGTH*c.WIDTH*c.HEIGHT)/1728)*d.QTY_ORIGNL)
        END TFEET,

    s.PROD_UDF4

    From Tables

    where P.Purchase_Order_Number=  @PO OR @PO is NULL


) T

GROUP BY Purchase_Order_Number
```

The inner query is simple, it is just a list of products with their type and their dimensions. Then I calculate the total weight of the product and the total cube of the product using its quantity.

Here is a sample of the result of the inner query:

```
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
|      PRODUCT       | QTY_ORIGNL | WEIGHT | LENGTH | WIDTH | HEIGHT | TWEIGHT |  TFEET   | PROD_UDF4 |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
| 18SP700002XBC00700 |          2 |      2 |     21 |    10 | 1      |       4 | 0.243054 | PG        |
| 1812340024B00604   |          1 |     16 |     18 |    15 | 7      |      16 | 1.09375  | CA        |
| 18SP700002MBC00700 |          4 |      2 |     21 |    15 | 1.5    |       8 | 1.093748 | PG        |
| 18SP700002SBC00700 |          2 |      1 |     20 |     9 | 1      |       2 | 0.208332 | PG        |
| 18SP700002LBC00700 |          4 |      2 |     21 |     9 | 1      |       8 | 0.4375   | PG        |
+--------------------+------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

And now I am supposed to take these items and their dimensions, and figure out how many boxes it will take to pack everything. CAs are already pre-packed boxes so no calculations required there. I need to take the PG items and using the weight and feet of the items, find the minimum amount of boxes needed.

Also, please tell me if I am going about this in the wrong way. I am trying to figure this out as I go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're simply missing a layer of aggregation in your pseudocode. While I'm not at all confident that this is the mechanism for determining how many cartons are needed in the real world, I'm trusting your logic here that this works for your use case.

```
declare @CartonMaxVolume int = 480;
declare @CartonMaxWeight int = 40;

select
    Cust_Po,
    (
        CaCartons
        + case
            when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < @CartonMaxVolume
                then 1
            when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume
                then PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight
            else
                PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume
        end
    ) TotalCartons
from
    (
        select
            T.Cust_Po,
            isnull(sum (T.TWEIGHT), '0') TotalWeight,
            isnull(cast((sum (T.TFEET)) as numeric(9,2)), '0' ) TotalFeet,
            sum(case when PROD_UDF4 = 'CA' then 1 end) CaCartons,
            sum(case when PROD_UDF4 = 'PG' then TWEIGHT end) PgWeight,
            sum(case when PROD_UDF4 = 'PG' then TFEET end) PgWeight
        from
            (
                select
                    Purchase_Order_Number,
                    d.PRODUCT,
                    d.QTY_ORIGNL,
                    c.WEIGHT,
                    c.LENGTH,
                    c.WIDTH,
                    c.HEIGHT,
                    case
                        when c.WEIGHT is null
                            THEN null 
                        else 
                            c.WEIGHT * d.QTY_ORIGNL
                    end TWEIGHT,
                    case 
                        when c.LENGTH is null or c.WIDTH is null or c.HEIGHT is null 
                            THEN null 
                        else 
                            ((c.LENGTH * c.WIDTH * c.HEIGHT) / 1728) * d.QTY_ORIGNL
                    end TFEET,
                    s.PROD_UDF4
                from
                    Tables
                where
                    P.Purchase_Order_Number = @PO 
                    or @PO is null
            ) T
        group by
            Purchase_Order_Number
    ) PurchaseOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of "knapsack problem" that is generally speaking a very hard problem to solve algorithmically. I would imagine, Transact SQL is not the best place tool for it. [Link talking about the knapsack problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/the-knapsack-problem/)